# LayoutParams move x and y

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to get an image to move to certain x and y withing this application.I have tried with layoutParams via searching but it is not working here is my full application code.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/myImage1" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></ImageView>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/marker" android:src="@drawable/marker"></ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

myapp Java

```
ImageView marker;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        marker=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.marker);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(35, 90, 0, 0);
        marker.setLayoutParams(lp);
        marker.invalidate();

       }
}
```

My end goal is to move the marker image over myImage1 at different Locations

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of the phone with this code:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)c).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidth = ((int)metrics.xdpi);
    screenHeight = ((int)metrics.ydpi);
```

You can use setPadding and the width and height of the phone can be got by the code above. I had positioning problems too and this was the solution.

Comment: Hmmm,Ok I am a dummy I guess could you elaborate on how to set the images position a little bit.

Comment: Something about that just don't seem right.Logging screenWidth screenHeight in the Normal emulator gives 160 and 160.

Comment: How are you supposed to use this?

Comment: Once you get the screenWidth and screenHeight they can be used as important parameters, because they are the space where you can draw your components. The positioning of images depends on a very important question: what XML element is the container of the pictures and what are its attributes. Depending on the container type you can vary with its attributes to create the desired positioning.